# Importing Maya Files into Blender

Tags: animation, mesh, objects, import

So i'm wondering if can can get a file I downloaded that runs on maya, which I don't have, to run on Blender.  If I try .fbx but it will totally destroy the rig. A better solution is if there is some sort of app that will allow me to do this could you tell me.

Comment: Did you try going into Edit -> Preferences -> Add-ons, and then in the drop-down that says "All" select "Import-Export," look for "Import-Export: FBX format" in the list and checking the box to enable it?  It might be enabled by default, so I'm not sure if this will help.  But it's worth a shot.

Comment: I already have this checked if I don't it will prevent me from importing the model entirely